# Problems installing updates / .NET Framework 4.6.1 /

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, updates, .net-framework

I have a HP Envy Notebook with windows 8.1. Since a week, I can't install updates / .NET Framework (I have also a lot of other computers with the same problem, but has to be more specific otherwise downvotes).

**Configuration**: 
Intel Core i7 - 4710MQ
2.5Ghz
8Gb Ram

**Installed .NET versions:**

- .NET 2.0 SP 2
- .NET 3.0 SP 2
- .NET 3.5 SP 1

**Installed virusscanner**:
Avast

**Problems:**
Everytime I start installing .NET 4.6.1 it fails:
It says it couldn't be installed and it has be undone..

But all updates fail for windows,like KB4056887 Security update for Adobe Flash Player

**What I have tried (to install the updates / .NET framework):**

1. Installing them manually ([Windows Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=4056887))
   [image: FAIL MANUALLY]
   [image: Error installing manually]
2. Trying to install them offline with [WSUS](http://download.wsusoffline.net/)
3. Cleaned SoftwareDistribution folder + sfc/scannow
4. Repaired missing DLLs after installation problems ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2260913/fix-updating-the--net-framework-may-fail-and-some-files-in-the-gac-may))
5. Running ccleaner / malwarebytes / ...

Sometimes I get errorcodes from windows, like 8024A000, 80070BC9 .. but it changes the whole time.

Internet connection is OK, tried on multiple networks / UTP + WIFI / ...

Who has another idea? Reinstalling is hard, because of very advanced software installation / custom drivers.

Comment: share the logs from **C:\Windows\logs\CBS**, this helps to analyze the issue

Answer (score 0):

Once try disabling all the antivirus and try it. And if it doesn't work mount your windows iso  and  with the help of dism you can install .net offline way. Just google on how to install windows features with iso .if all else fails just do an implace upgrade which will fix most  of the issues

Comment: Already tried.. No results..

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft tool Fix Windows Update errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness tool (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947821/fix-windows-update-errors-by-using-the-dism-or-system-update-readiness) fixed the problem for me. I used Windows 8.1 for the 2012 R2 Server.